# Spring instanciar objeto com @Value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy

No meu `application.properties` tem o `algumaCoisa=joao`, e quando eu rodo o `java -jar nomedo.jar`, ele vem null, alguém pode me explicar por que isso acontece e como eu arrumo?

```
@Component
class TesteClass{
    @Value("${algumaCoisa}")
    String nome

    String nomeDoValue
    String sobrenome

    TesteClass(info){

        this.nomeDoValue = nome
        this.sobrenome = info.sobrenome
    }
}

@Service
class AlgumService{
    //...
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        def objeto = new TesteClass(info)
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aponte o local do arquivo de properties para o spring usar na sua classe:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:/config.properties}")
class TesteClass{
    @Value("${algumaCoisa}")
    String nome

    String nomeDoValue
    String sobrenome

    TesteClass(info){

        this.nomeDoValue = nome
        this.sobrenome = info.sobrenome
    }
}
```

Segue documentação do spring sobre o assunto:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html